# Recursive search subdirectories

Tags: makefile

I have a project directory structure is as follows:

```
Source-----------------
---Project1------------
-----------Project1_vA-
-----------Project1_vB-
---Project2------------
-----------Project2_vA-
-----------Project2_vB-
---Project3------------
-----------Project3_vA-
```

I'm trying to write makefile for recursive build lib in all subdirectories:

```
DIRS    := $(dir $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*/));
$(info $(DIRS))     

for item in $(DIRS); do \
    $(info sublib)      \
    $(info $(item))         \
    if [[ "$item" == "$LOCAL_PATH/glm/" ||      \
    "$item" == "$LOCAL_PATH/common/" ]]     \
    then                            \
        continue;                                                               \
    fi                                                                          \

    SUBDIRS := $(dir $(wildcard $(item)/*/))                            \
    $(info $(SUBDIRS))                                                          \
    for subitem in $(SUBDIRS); do                                       \
        include $(CLEAR_VARS)                                                   \
        $(info $(subitem))                                                      \
        LOCAL_MODULE            := $(subitem)                                           \                                       \
        LOCAL_CFLAGS            := -g -fexceptions                              \
        LOCAL_ARM_MODE          := arm                                          \
        LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := $(subitem)/*.cpp                             \
                                $(subitem)/main.cpp                             \
        LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  := common                                           \
        LOCAL_LDLIBS            := -llog -lGLESv2   \
        include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)                                         \
    done;                                                                       \
done;
```

But, something wrong in the loop block - `$(info $(item))` - displays spaces.

`$(info $(DIRS))` - displays `"Source/Project1/ Source/Project2/ Source/Project3/;"`

Help please.

Comment: Why wouldn't it display spaces?  That's how wildcard works, it returns a space-separated list of paths that match the wildcard operation.  Assuming `LOCAL_DIR` is set to `Source` the results look fine to me.  Perhaps if you told us what you _expected_ it to return we could advise you...

Comment: Also, that `for` loop is a shell loop; it has no place in the middle of a makefile like that.  This makefile, as you've transcribed it here, is not right at all.

Comment: I want to bild for each subdirectory (Project1_vA, Project1_vB..) library. To do this I need to create a unique name for LOCAL_MODULE like a "libProject1_vA". At the time of bild, I do not know the number of subdirectories, so I need to dynamically generate a list of subdirectories and bild a library for each of them. In the first cycle, I want to bypass all the project directories. In the second cycle, I want to bypass all subdirectories of the projects.

Comment: I know that "for" is a shell loop, but I don't see a way for recursive lib build in a one common makefile.

Answer (score 1):

What about using find?

```
DIRS := `find . -type d`
PROJECT_DIRS := $(filter ...,$(DIRS))
NON_PROJECT_DIRS := $(filter-out ...,$(DIRS))

.PHONY: $(DIRS)

$(PROJECT_DIRS): $(NON_PROJECT_DIRS)
    ... rules for making projects ...

$(NON_PROJECT_DIRS):
    ... rules for making sub dirs ...
```